# Return the repeated elements in an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to get the duplicated elements of given array in a new array how ever I dont know where am I getting trapped and why it doesnt work.

```
var arraye: [Int] = []

func fn(list: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    for var a = 0; a < list.count; a++ {
        for var b = 1; b < list.count; b++ {
            if list[a] == list[b] {
                if contains(arraye, list[a]) == false {
                        arraye.append(list[b])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return arraye
}

println(fn([1,2,4,3]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm has a mistake in it:

You have to start the search for the duplicate **after** the "original" element. Therefore you must initialize `b` to `a + 1`.

```
func fn(list: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    for var a = 0; a < list.count; a++ {
        for var b = a + 1; b < list.count; b++ {
            if list[a] == list[b] && !contains(arraye, list[a]) {
                arraye.append(list[b])
            }
        }
    }
    return arraye
}

println(fn([1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4]))
```

Prints

```
[1, 4]
```

BTW:

The lines `if list[a] == list[b] {` and `if contains(arraye, list[a]) == false` can be unified and `contains(arraye, list[a]) == false` is more commonly written as `!contains(arraye, list[a])`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some info: there's another way to do this, with `NSCountedSet`. I believe it's more lightweight to use than calling `contains` multiple times.

```
func fn(list: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    let uniques = NSCountedSet()
    uniques.addObjectsFromArray(list)
    var result = [AnyObject]()
    for item in uniques {
        if uniques.countForObject(item) > 1 {
            result.append(item)
        }
    }
    return result as! [Int]
}

println(fn([1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4]))  // prints [1, 4]
```

*Of course it's not "pure" Swift anymore, because `NSCountedSet` is from Foundation.*